# How to open a new window with the same custom user agent in ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

Im Building a **webview** app in ElectronJs, Im using a **Custom User Agent** to make the user interact with the webApp. When the user clicks on links that has **target="_blank"** property, it opens a new tab and not using the custom user agent.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the target=_black will create a new browserWindow Object so a think that you could track this events with the webContents api and apply the custom userAgent to this new browserwindow objects. for example:

you need this webContents event on your main window

```
win.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ url }) => {
   /* 
     Here you will allow the browserWindow creation and configure it
     look a bit of the documentation here https://www.electronjs.org/es/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssetwindowopenhandlerhandler
   */
}
```

this SetWindowOpenHandler event will allow the window creation, now with the event did-create-window you will get the new BrowserWindow object and with that reference you will be able to set the custom userAgent

```
win.webContents.on('did-create-window', (childWindow) => {
  /*
     Here you can use childWindow to set the new user agent for example
     here documentation for did-create-window https://www.electronjs.org/es/docs/latest/api/web-contents#evento-did-create-window
  */
     childwindow.webContents.setUserAgent('your-custom-user-agent)
  
});
```

I hope that helps you, bye!